# How to properly set up a network bridge using bridge-utils using wlan0 as the internet "source"?

Tags: network-bridge

Hey everyone this is my first post so go easy on me.

I currently have a laptop with Ubuntu Studio 12.04 Beta 2 that is supplying a wireless internet connection to a windows 7 desktop computer that's connected directly to the laptop through Ethernet.
I'm using the "shared to other computers" method in network manager but I believe it doesn't work with what I want to do. I would like to have the windows computer on the same subnet as every other computer in my house (192.168.1.x) so I can use LAN applications (MIDI over WiFi, Bonjour etc.) on the windows computer without having to run a massive cable to the router.

I've been googling endlessly and tried multiple configurations in the `/etc/network/interfaces` file without success. All of them would report "`cannot add wlan0 to bridge`"

This is the last configuration I tried:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
auto wlan0
auto br0

iface wlan0 inet dhcp
    wireless-essid 3GF2
    wireless-key passw*rd
    wireless-mode managed

iface eth0 inet manual
up ip link set eth0 up

iface br0 inet manual
    bridge_ports wlan0 eth0
```

Is there a specific way to make this work? What am I missing?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can do the same thing by forwarding packets from ethernet card to wireless card. In order to do that, [wlan0 - wireless card; eth0 - ethernet card].

Do this on your ubuntu machine.

1. `ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.1` (or whatever you want)
2. Enable ip_forward by  `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`
3. Enable forwarding in IPTABLES by `iptables -A FORWARD --in-interface
   wlan0 -j ACCEPT`
4. Enable NAT mode to connect to internet by `iptables --table nat -A POSTROUTING --out-interface eth0 -j MASQUERADE`

On your windows machine set IP to 192.168.1.2 and gateway to 192.168.1.1 (ubuntu eth0 ip address)

No need to create bridges

Comment: Can't seem to get it to work. I've run the commands exactly as you told me except I put different IP addresses for both the eth0 card and the windows computer. They're both are within 192.168.1.x. Should I have the network configuration for eth0 on "Shared with other computers" or Manual or even disabled?

Comment: It seems that I can get the LAN to work because I can access the shared folders onthe the ubuntu machine but on the windows machine I can't see any of  other computers on the network and I can't get internet.

Comment: type iptables -L and check the rules have applied. and type "cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward" and check the value is 1. Did you set the gateway to ubuntu machines ip on windows

Comment: Indeed i have but no luck yet. ipforward spits out 1 and this is the output for iptables `Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination    ` what happens now is internet access on the ubuntu machine cuts out whenever I have my two machines connected. Any thoughts? Thanks a lot for your help btw

Comment: Sorry I've made a mistake you should change wlan0 with eth0 when typing iptables commands.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to circumvent bridging using one of the Ubuntu ICS guides.
The main page is [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing)

I used the Ubuntu Internet Gateway Method (iptables) Method changing
External WAN: eth0 -> wlan0
Internal LAN: eth1 -> eth0

It worked immediately! The only downside is that it assumes both computers are Ubuntu flavors.

Jump directly to the [Gateway Method](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing#Ubuntu_Internet_Gateway_Method_.28iptables.29)